# Hide point views from MPChart LineChart

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart

I'd like to hide (or better, to not draw) the plot points upon the drawn line.

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

Have you got any suggestion on how to do it? I read the documentation but I found nothing useful for this.

Thanks in advance! Bye!

Answer (score 57, accepted):

By the looks of it, you are using v2.0.7, nonetheless use the below method.

```
lineDataSet.setDrawCircles(false);
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, and there is the documentation page where you can find it: https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/DataSet-classes-in-detail

Comment: Thank you guys! Sorry but I was in a hurry and read it quickly. I think this library deserves tips for more than a beer ;)

Comment: Its possible to hide particular points?